# Why do element selectors supersede the :host selector in custom elements with shadow DOM

Tags: css, css-selectors, shadow-dom, css-specificity

If you create a custom element with a shadow root, and add style rules to it with a `:host` selector:

```
<style>
    :host {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

And then add styles in the light DOM for the custom element, using an element selector:

```
 <style>
    custom-element {
        color: blue;
    }
</style>
```

The styles in the element selector supersede the styles in the `:host` selector. This is, arguably, ideal behaviour - but I am curious why this is true... if `:host` is a pseduo-class, should it not have a higher specificity than `custom-element`, and take precedence? If this is an exception to the rule, is it documented in specifications somewhere?

## [See JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/6bnu94tv/)

Comment: CMIIW, but that might not be the case. If you inspect the element you would notice that `:host` has similar specificity than `custom-element`. If it was overwritten it would be crossed out.
[screenshot inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFnGg.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true because it's the ideal behaviour as you stated.

It is implemented as wanted by the [CSS Scoping Module Level 1](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping/#shadow-cascading) specification:

> When comparing two declarations that have different tree contexts, then for normal rules the declaration earlier in the shadow-including tree order wins, and for important rules the declaration coming later in the shadow-including tree order wins.
>
> Note: This is the opposite of how scoped styles work.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @Supersharp has said think of it this way:

The use of `:host` is similar to a browsers default styling for all built in elements.

When you add *ANY* CSS you override the default values.

This is just how CSS works and I am very glad it does.